# Google Guice. Methods annotated with @Provides annotation are not invoked

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I am a new to Guice dependecy injection, hope someone could explain me why my code doesn't work.

here is the class that extends AbstractModule:

```
public class WebCoreModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
        public SomeFactory getSomeFactory() {
            return new SomeFactoryImpl();
        }

 }
```

and in the other class i have a private member

```
private static @Inject SomeFactory factory;
```

I'd like to invoke methods on `factory` object, but it is always null. Also I set a breakpoint on `getSomeFactory()` method and it is never being invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you getting an instance of "other class"? Presumably not via the `Injector`.

Comment: My 'other class' is AspectJ aspect, so it is being created by the framework. Does it matter how instance of the class that uses dependency injection is being created?

Comment: Absolutely it does. If the Guice framework does not create your class it has no idea it exists and cannot carry out injection. This is the same for all DI frameworks, except if they run some type of byte code enhancement.

Comment: Alright, so having method annotated with @ Provides and a private member with @ Inject in the class that is consuming injected object is not enough.. What should I do so Guice will perform DI?

Comment: Would seem that reading the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted) would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All i needed was in the `configure()` method of the `WebCoreModule` following line:

```
requestStaticInjection(ClassThatIsUsingInjectedMember.class);
```